# Tinder like navigation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-pageview

How to achieve this in Flutter? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

[image: Tinderbar]

Comment: Use the PageView widget https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J1gE9xvph-A

Comment: @MSpeed Thank you for your answer, I tried PageView and i almost did it by changing viewportFraction, but it's look little bit different in different screen sizes. I was wondering, How do i align the first item (which is profile icon) into beginning of the screen, and last item (which is chat icon) into end of the screen properly? Maybe i should calculate the viewportFraction based on the screen width, but i don't know how :))

Comment: @MSpeed finally i did it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a package that you can use - https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tindercard

Source code for your reference - https://github.com/ShaunRain/flutter_tindercard

Comment: Thank you, but actually, the answer is not related my question, sorry!